# The Thirty-Sixth-Best All Time Rep Score

Tags: discussion, reputation, statistics

Does anybody have an idea of how the 36th-most all-time rep score has evolved over the life of the site?  Really, I am asking about the min rep score to be on the front page of the all-time users page.  It seems that, while right now it hovers around 39k, I recall not that long ago it was less than 30k, and I am sure it was a lot less a year ago.

Comment: What is so special about $36$?

Comment: @Vishal The "users" tab has 36 entries per page. So these users show up on the first tab.

Comment: @Lord_Farin which tab or page, any link.

Comment: Well, 36 is a perfect square.

Comment: Not only that, @BabyDragon, it's also a triangle (number).

Comment: SE was sending out coffee mugs/ T-shirts to top 30 in late 2011 or early 2012. I don't remember for sure when it was, but I do remember that I qualified with about 14k of rep at the time.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: That's perfect.  I just wanted to get a sense for the global behavior of the site - who's been contributing when. It's an interesting dynamic within the first page alone - even the first, say, 3 pages.

Comment: I'm no longer sure that it was top 30. See [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4040/11619) for more about the timing. I have a vague recollection that it was 20 users per page in the rep leagues at that time?

Comment: Awww...man!  Missed the boat!  Nice tchachkies for sure.

Comment: @Vishal [This page](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all).

Comment: @Lord_Farin It was not me who asked for the page. I had found it.

Comment: Sorry Vishal. @Shobhit See above.

Comment: @Jyrki: Nice coffee mug, too: holds a very respectable amount!

Comment: Indeed, @Brian. Slightly bigger than my old reliable MSRI mug from '90.

Comment: I don't have enough time right now (so I can't do it for you), but I think you should be able to digest that kind of information using [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/new). Even if not precisely, then at least an approximate (e.g. using post date as the time of all the upvotes the post has).

Comment: I've tried to write a data-explorer query that would find the answer, but it became complicated and it times out, so I guess that's not the best approach.

Comment: @dtldarek: Thanks.  I was hoping someone would, as I do not have the time to do so.  That said, does the complication lie in accessing the ranks through various times?

Comment: @RonGordon Mostly, however, just calculating the approximate of reputation feels wrong. For example the daily 200 rep cap makes the computations non-uniform, but without it the differences are too big for the result mean anything.

Answer (score 3):

Being on the third page, I noted at the beginning of the summer that the top score on page 3 was about $20k$, which registered because it is the highest point at which user privileges change. It is now $21.7k$. Around that level there are lots of regular users who have acquired points over time, some who seem to be less active, and some who are increasing fast relative to those around them.

Answer (score 2):

You can view top users by reputation at the end for each week/month/year in [reputation leagues](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/).

I am not sure to whether the reputation is exactly the same as it was at that time. (I do not know influence of the posts that were deleted since then.)

- [2016-01-01](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/month/math/2016-01-01?sort=totalreputation)
- [2015-01-01](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/month/math/2015-01-01?sort=totalreputation)
- [2014-01-01](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/month/math/2014-01-01?sort=totalreputation)
- [2013-01-01](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/month/math/2013-01-01?sort=totalreputation)
- [2012-01-01](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/month/math/2012-01-01?sort=totalreputation)
- [2011-01-01](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/month/math/2011-01-01?sort=totalreputation)
- [2010-07-01](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/month/math/2010-07-01?sort=totalreputation)

---

You can also have a look at snapshots of the relevant page in Internet Archive (a.k.a. Wayback Machine): http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all

Comment: This also ignores suspensions that were in force at the time.

Comment: Interesting that you brought back this question onto the main page.  The 36th highest rep is now well over 60k and growing rapidly.  Maybe we should take bets on when it will be 100k.

Comment: 93.9K now. Will definitely hit 100K in 2017